# Detail about a Normality Condition in Lower Central Series

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

While preparing for my Quals by reading Rotman's Group Theory textbook I encountered that a Lower Central Series is a normal series if it reaches $1$.  We define the lower central series as
$$ \gamma_1 (G) = G; \quad \gamma_{i+1}(G) = [\gamma_i (G), G]. $$
While playing with this series it occurred that its not obvious to me why, in general, $\gamma_{i+1}(G) \trianglelefteq \gamma_i (G)$.  I've worked out an attempt at showing this, and hope to make sure it's correct.  I also suspect there's a cleaner way and would appreciate any help.  I did see a similar question asked on this site, but the answer did not satisfy me.  Here's my attempt:

I first am able to show that for each $i$, $\gamma_i (G) $ char $G$ and $\gamma_{i+1}(G) \leq \gamma_i (G)$.  This is not too bad.

Now let $x,y \in \gamma_i (G)$ and $g \in G$.  Then we have

\begin{align*} y[x,g]y^{-1} ={}& yxgx^{-1}g^{-1}y^{-1}\\ ={}&
(yxy^{-1})(ygy^{-1})(yx^{-1}y^{-1})(yg^{-1}y^{-1}).   \end{align*}

Since $\gamma_i (G)$ is characteristic in $G$ then it is normal in $G$ and $yxy^{-1} = x^{\prime} \in \gamma_i$ and thus we have

$$ y[x,g]y^{-1} = [x^{\prime}, ygy^{-1}] \in \gamma_{i+1}(G). $$

Any mistakes here?  Also, I feel like I can somehow use characteristic to get this more easily, but came up short!  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you are almost there. As you say, since $\gamma_{i+1}(G)$ is characteristic in $G$, it is in particular normal in $G$. So if $\gamma_{i+1}(G)\leq\gamma_i(G)$ then $\gamma_{i+1}(G)$ is normal also in the possibly smaller group $\gamma_i(G)$.

Comment: Yes!  Thank you, that's totally right and now it's clear why we get the normality condition.